# Riverpod Provider.family and HookConsumerWidget not refreshing the UI

Tags: flutter, setstate, riverpod, flutter-state

NOTA BENE: I ended up using `ConsumerWidget` instead of `HookConsumerWidget` and using exclusively Riverpod 2.0 classes.

---

I am having a very hard time understanding why the UI is not refreshing with Riverpod and Hook, and especially while using `HookConsumerWidget` and `ProviderFamily`, passing one argument.

Some precisions: `MediaThumbnail` is called by `MediaThumbnailAPI` with a unique key set to it, `MediaThumbnailAPI`  is inside a gridviewbuilder (can item inside a gridviewbuilder be independantly rebuilt without rebuilding the whole gridview? I assume that it is possible).

My understanding is that  bool `isFavorite = ref.watch(favoriteFamilyProvider(id)).isMediaFavorite(id);` is not triggering a `setState` (equivalent with riverpod hook) when there is a long press while it should, but I have no idea what is missing in my syntax.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import '../../../../favorite_provider.dart';
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart' as universal_io;

class MediaThumbnail extends HookConsumerWidget {
  final String id;
  final String fileExtension;
  final universal_io.File imageFile;
  final String urlEndpoint;
  final String description;
  final double thumbnailRadius;
  final String mimeType;

  const MediaThumbnail(this.imageFile, this.urlEndpoint, this.id,
      this.fileExtension, this.description, this.thumbnailRadius, this.mimeType,
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    bool isFavorite = ref.watch(favoriteFamilyProvider(id)).isMediaFavorite(id); // probably the problematic line of code.
    return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onLongPress: () {

          ref.read(favoriteProvider.notifier)
              .toggleFav(id, fileExtension, description); // this one works successfully and change the content of imageMetadataBox 
          isFavorite = ref.read(favoriteFamilyProvider(id)).isMediaFavorite(id); // the isFavorite value is correctly updated
          print("is favorite: $isFavorite");
        },
       
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: FileImage(imageFile), fit: BoxFit.cover),
              )),
          if (isFavorite) // this does not refresh
            Positioned(
              top: 5,
              left: 60,
              right: .0,
              child: Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    _buildIcon(16, Colors.white),
                    _buildIcon(13, Colors.pinkAccent),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
        ]));
  }
}
```

*favorite_provider.dart*

```dart
final favoriteFamilyProvider =
Provider.family<FavoriteFamilyNotifier, String>(
        (_, myId) => FavoriteFamilyNotifier(myId));

class FavoriteFamilyNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  FavoriteFamilyNotifier(String myId) : super(false) {}

  bool isMediaFavorite(String myId) {
    Store store = objectbox.store;

    Box<MediaMetadata> imageMetadataBox = store.box<MediaMetadata>();

    final qBuilder =
       imageMetadataBox.query(MediaMetadata_.myId.equals(myId));
    final query = qBuilder.build();
    var results = query.find();
    bool isFavorite = results.isNotEmpty;
    print("$myId is favorite? $isFavorite");
    return isFavorite;
  }
```

Many thanks to those experienced with this library.

NB: I use "myId" because ObjectBox reserve the "id" keyword for its internal database, so `MediaMetadata_.myId` is like a 32 long String, while `MediaMetadata_.id` is an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your problem is that you are using `Provider` to implement a class that extends `StateNotifier`. To solve the problem, change `Provider` to `StateNotifierProvider`.

I also want to point out that `StateNotifier` is a deprecated practice. Use `Notifier` to implement your `FavoriteFamilyNotifier`.

It also seems more logical to use the `myId` field in the `isMediaFavorite()` method, which you pass as a field when creating `FavoriteFamilyNotifier(myId)`. **Or** get rid of `.family`, because it's not at all clear what role it plays if you create a class with `FavoriteFamilyNotifier(String myId)` and then don't use that field at all.

And it's not very clear why you use `HookConsumerWidget`, which is not used inside the widget in this example.

Comment: thank you so much will have a closer look once I can! If StateNotifier is deprecated what about StateNotifierProvider? Shouldn't it also be deprecated?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL By and large it's worth moving to `Notifier` as the newest solution :)

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL And yes, don't confuse `StateNotifier` with `StateNotifierProvider`! It's a completely different thing! The first one is needed to `extends` from it and create business logic inside your class. And the second to provide (di) your first class. Same `Notifier` and `NotifierProvider`.

Comment: I am not confusing both, what I mean is that I should then use `NotifierProvider` since you originally recommended to change `Provider` to `StateNotifierProvider`.

Comment: Thank you I was able to make it work thanks to your input. It's really frustrating that even the recent documentation and tutorials are already deprecated so for people like me discovering the library it's a huge headache. One last thing, would you recommend to have two providers in my usecase? I ended up having one provider for each bool isFavorite, and I have another Provider for the list of favorite items, respectively `NotifierProvider.family<FavNotifier, bool, String>` and   `StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteFilesNotifier, AsyncValue<List<File>>>`

Comment: You can use two providers, but consider using `AsyncNotifierProvider` instead of `StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteFilesNotifier, AsyncValue<List<File>>>>`.

Comment: For now it works so why should I consider the former instead of the latter?

Comment: `StateNotifierProvider` will soon be marked deprecated :)

Comment: Thanks, I made the change and everything is working fine :)